# Name a famous actor

Tags: riddle, knowledge, movies

In my name you can find a time of light,

and I almost share it with a certain Christmas song.

In my famous work, I am a mad man

accompanied by D major and a vintage accent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> Daniel Day-Lewis

In my name you can find a time of light,

> Day

and I almost share it with a certain Christmas song.

> carol, or Lewis Carroll

In my famous work, I am a mad man

> *There Will Be Blood* depicts an oil man's descent into madness

accompanied by D major and a vintage accent.

> Not sure about this one...

*Edit*:

> The vintage accent refers to Daniel Day-Lewis' old Californian accent in There Will Be Blood, and the soundtrack for the movie is Brahms' Violin Concerto in D-major.

Comment: Yes! If you don't mind I'll add the missing part to your answer. :)

Comment: That D Major reference really left-footed me...